# onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) of second activity not loaded?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a question about android programming in Eclipse. I have 2 activities that one is being called after an image button click, using the code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
```

Now, when I want to do the programming of back image button in second activity (`activity_about`) I can't, because `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is not being run in my opinion. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Perhaps you should add more info; do you get an error and what is that?

Comment: you are programming in Java. Not Eclipse. Damn...

Comment: Now, I Want to learn this new language called eclipse :D haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did not misunderstand your question, you are trying to open the second activity by `setContentView`? In Android you are opening Activities with Intents and when you want to return you just call `finish()` in your second Activity. Opening your acitivity about is done with

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

while AboutActivity is having the `setContentView`

Comment: yes my problem was incorrect opening of second activity... thank you very much ! :)